# PDE-DirichletCondition needs to be linear

Tags: finite-element-method, finite-difference-method

I am trying to solve the following multi-field problem in MMA 12, however, this probelm cannot be solved, i.e., **error**:

> **DirichletCondition [...]  needs to be linear.**

I attached the code here:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];

PDE1 = (s[t, x])^2 D[u[t, x], x, x] == D[u[t, x], t];
PDE2 = 2 \[Epsilon] D[s[t, x], x, x] + 0.5 (1 - s[t, x])/\[Epsilon] - 
    s[t, x] \[CapitalEpsilon]1 (D[u[t, x], x])^2/\[ScriptCapitalG] == 
   D[s[t, x], t]/10;

lr = 25;
ll = -25;
\[CapitalEpsilon]1 = 1;
\[ScriptCapitalG] = 1;
u0 = 10;
\[Epsilon] = 0.125;

\[CapitalOmega] = Line[{{ll}, {lr}}];

tmax = 1;
bcs1 = {u[t, ll] == -u0 t, u[t, lr] == u0 t};
bcs2 = {s[t, ll] == 1, s[t, lr] == 1};
bcs3 = {Derivative[0, 1][s][t, ll] == 0, 
   Derivative[0, 1][s][t, lr] == 0};
ic = {s[0, x] == 1, u[0, x] == 0};
{uu1, vv1} = 
 NDSolveValue[{PDE1, PDE2, bcs1, bcs2, bcs3, ic}, {u, 
   s}, {x} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], {t, 0, tmax}, 
  Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
    "MeshOptions" -> {MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001}}]

{Plot3D[uu1[t, x], {x} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], {t, 0, tmax}, 
  Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> Hue, AxesLabel -> Automatic], 
 Plot3D[vv1[t, x], {x} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], {t, 0, tmax}, 
  Mesh -> None, ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotRange -> All, 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic]}
{Plot[uu1[tmax, x], {x} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]], 
 Plot[vv1[tmax, x], {x} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], PlotRange -> All]}
```

> **In this benchmark test, *input parameters and BCs are fixed.***

If I remove **bcs3**, then error:

> FindRoot::sszero: The step size in the search has become less than the
>   tolerance prescribed by the PrecisionGoal option, but the function
>   value is still greater than the tolerance prescribed by the
>   AccuracyGoal option.
>
> FindRoot::nosol: Linear equation encountered that has no solution.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You need an IC on $u(t, x)$.  Also, your `bc1` is different from the one in the original.  And, you have a scale of 1000 in your 2nd PDE.

Comment: Since you call this a benchmark, where's the reference solution?

Comment: @LouisB  u[0, x] == 0 is enough?

Comment: @xzczd I have modified the equation and added new code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have not specified enough initial conditions `NDSolve` will try to solve this as a stationary problem. For this it parses `Derivative[0, 1][s][t, ll]` as a nonlinear `DirichletCondition`. To fix this you should specify a initial condition for `u`.